# TSLINT : TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: tslint

Getting the below error while trying to run tslint. The linting fails and no issues are being reported for any typescript (ts) file.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Rule.SelectorRule [as constructor] (d:\android\node_modules\codelyzer\selectorNameBase.js:23:24)
    at new Rule (d:\android\node_modules\codelyzer\directiveSelectorRule.js:18:47)
    at Object.loadRules (C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tslint\lib\ruleLoader.js:47:36)
    at Linter.getEnabledRules (C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tslint\lib\linter.js:168:44)
    at Linter.lint (C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tslint\lib\linter.js:81:33)
    at doValidate (C:\Users\XXXXX\.vscode\extensions\eg2.tslint-0.17.0\server\server.js:393:20)
    at validateTextDocument (C:\Users\XXXXX\.vscode\extensions\eg2.tslint-0.17.0\server\server.js:300:27)
    at Delayer.d.trigger [as task] (C:\Users\XXXXX\.vscode\extensions\eg2.tslint-0.17.0\server\server.js:486:9)
    at completionPromise.Promise.then (C:\Users\XXXXX\.vscode\extensions\eg2.tslint-0.17.0\server\delayer.js:20:35)
```

**Steps to Reproduce (Manually)**

1. Open terminal
2. `ng new trial`
3. Successfully installed all packages with no warnings

   `Installed packages for tooling via npm.
   Project 'trial' successfully created.`
4. `cd trial`
5. `tslint --project tsconfig.json -c tslint.json`

**Steps to Reproduce (IDE)**

1. Open project in VSCODE
2. Open the project
3. Open any TS file
4. Notice "TSLint: Error" in bottom right corner of IDE
5. Open tslint console

**package.json**

{ "name": "trial", "version": "0.0.0", "license": "MIT", "scripts": { "ng": "ng", "start": "ng serve", "build": "ng build --prod", "test": "ng test", "lint": "ng lint", "e2e": "ng e2e" }, "private": true, "dependencies": { "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0", "@angular/common": "^5.2.0", "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0", "@angular/core": "^5.2.0", "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0", "@angular/http": "^5.2.0", "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0", "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0", "@angular/router": "^5.2.0", "core-js": "^2.4.1", "rxjs": "^5.5.6", "zone.js": "^0.8.19" }, "devDependencies": { "@angular/cli": "1.6.8", "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0", "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0", "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3", "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2", "@types/node": "~6.0.60", "codelyzer": "^4.0.1", "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0", "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1", "karma": "~2.0.0", "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0", "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1", "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0", "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2", "protractor": "~5.1.2", "ts-node": "~4.1.0", "tslint": "~5.9.1", "typescript": "~2.5.3" } }

**npm list --depth 0**

```
+-- @angular/animations@5.2.5
+-- @angular/cdk@5.2.1
+-- @angular/cli@1.7.0
+-- @angular/common@5.2.5
+-- @angular/compiler@5.2.5
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.5
+-- @angular/core@5.2.5
+-- @angular/forms@5.2.5
+-- @angular/http@5.2.5
+-- @angular/material@5.2.1
+-- @angular/platform-browser@5.2.5
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.5
+-- @angular/router@5.2.5
+-- @types/jasmine@2.8.6
+-- @types/node@9.4.6
+-- codelyzer@4.1.0
+-- core-js@2.5.3
+-- jasmine-core@2.99.1
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
+-- karma@2.0.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
+-- karma-cli@1.0.1
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.1
+-- karma-remap-istanbul@0.6.0
+-- protractor@5.3.0
+-- rxjs@5.5.6
+-- ts-helpers@1.1.2
+-- ts-node@4.1.0
+-- tslint@5.9.1
+-- typescript@2.6.2
+-- zone.js@0.8.20
```

Comment: Are you using TypeScript 2.7? TS lint 5.9.1 [doesn't work with it currently](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3711)

Comment: Using TypeScript 2.6.2.